# Forvalues within if statement

Tags: loops, if-statement, stata

I've been searching SO for answers to this particular question, but wasn't able to find any. I have two groups of variables linking people in a dataset to their mothers and fathers respectively. My goal is to link people with their siblings. My dataset looks something like this:

```
person_id mom_id father id  child_1_mom child_2_mom child_1_dad child_2_dad
```

I'm only interested in keeping children who have the same father and mother, which means that I'm making observations missing (only the child variables) if one of the `child_*_mom` person IDs does not match any of the `child_*_father` IDs. I've been trying different things, but my best guess is something like this code, just to illustrate what I'm doing.

```
forvalues i=1(1)17 {;
    replace child_`i'_mom="" if
        (forvalues j=1(1)17 {;
        (child_`i'_mom!=child_`j'_dad) &
        };
        (child_`i'_mom!=child_18_dad));
    };
```

As you can see, it's a little creative, but the best I've come up with. I have 17 child variables for mothers and 18 child variables for father (some in my dataset have 18 children). The reason why I don't want to do this manually is that I have to do the above for 20 years in total, and I'm planning to macro the number of child variables for both moms and dads at a later point.

My question is then: Is there any way to do a `forvalues` loop within an `if` statement, within a loop? Or is there a smarter way to solve this problem?

---

Further explanation:

Okay, so i'll try to elaborate a little further on the issue.

Originally the dataset looks like this

```
person_id mother_id father_id
```

then i've sorted the data, first in terms of `mother_id`, and made a variable, such that the data looks like this

```
person_id mother_id mother_n
     11      1         1  
     12      1         2
     13      2         1
     14      2         2
     15      2         3
```

and so on. This has been done for both mother and father. Then i reshape both of the datasets, such that

```
mother_id child_1 child_2 child_3
     1       11      12      .
     2       13      14      15
```

From this resulting dataset (for both father and mother), i've merged these dataset onto the original dataset, such that

```
   person_id mother_id mother_n child_1_m child_2_m child_3_m child_1_f child_2_f
     11      1         1          11         12      .          ?          ?
     12      1         2          11         12      .          ?          ?
     13      2         1          13         14      15         ?          ?
     14      2         2          13         14      15         ?          ?
     15      2         3          13         14      15         ?          ?
```

thus i have variables for both children of the mother, and children of the father. Next up i want to make every variableobservation missing, where a `child_ID` is not in both `child_*_m` group of variables and the `child_*_f` group of variables.

So the idea is that i want to make an automated procedure, that does this within a loop, without manually having to `replace if ...' numerous times through out the program, because i have to do it for multiple years, with different maximum amount of children.

Hope this clearifies.

Comment: `for`* loops within `if` qualifiers: can't be done. I am lost on why these data are in this form. I can imagine person identifier, mother identifier, father identifier, and can see that parent identifiers might be missing. Why so many variables?

Comment: This comes from danish data including every person in the country at a given year. Initially the rawdata includes every person in denmark, with an identifier for their mother and their father. We need to compare peoples educational level with their siblings (with same parents). So i'm making a dataset to merge every child of a given person (mother or father) unto every person in denmark, by their mother and father identifier, so yea. It's a little wierd looking at the moment, but i'm only making the data - not analyzing it hehe.

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like this:

```
gen byte mark = 1
forvalues i = 1/17 {
    replace mark = mark * inlist(child_`i'_mom, mom_id   , .) * ///
                          inlist(child_`i'_dad, father_id, .)
}
```

This will create a binary variable that is 1 when all siblings have the same father and mother and 0 otherwise. In your subsequent analysis you can add the `if mark == 1` condition to your commands to ensure that you use the sub-sample you want.

This is only preliminary code intended to get you started. One thing you should think about is that I made missing values OK because not everybody has 17 siblings, but what when the father of one of the siblings is unknown? You might want to look into things like that before adapting this code to your situation.

Comment: Thank you very much for this suggestion, i will look into it, although i would like to avoid markings in general. And also thank you for the reminder :).

Comment: I tend to prefer marking as it leaves the data intact, but you can always type `keep if mark == 1` before you start the analysis. Just remember _not_ to save your data...

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to (gently) push you into further explaining your data structure and variable definitions.

If each observation is a person (`perid`), who is already linked to his mother (`momid`) and father (`fathid`), then grouping siblings is just a matter of `sort`ing. Below an example:

```
clear all
set more off

*---------- example data ---------------

set obs 20

scalar a = 1
scalar b = 5

set seed 395

gen perid = _n
gen momid = floor((b-a+1)*runiform() + a)
gen fathid = floor((b-a+1)*runiform() + a)

list

*---------- group siblings -------------

isid momid fathid perid, sort

list, sepby(momid fathid)
```

What am I missing or missunderstanding? How can you improve your post?

Comment: ignore this, not enough characters :)

Comment: i added further explanation in the original post.

Comment: Okay i've tried your code and thank you very much for the attempt of solving my problem. However, this is not exactly what i wanted. I've gotten a description of the dataset, and it's been decided before hand that it has to look like the one i added to my original post.

Answer (score 0):

So I now understand your question as follows:

You want to keep persons when the mother only became children from one father and the father only became children from one mother.

I would stick to the dataset in its original form. As I understand it now that is a list of children with mother ids and father ids. If all children with the same mother also have the same father, then we know that the first condition is true. This is the first line in the example. If all the children with the same father also have the same mother we know that the second condition is true. This is the second line in the example. Multiplying these Boolean variables means that both conditions have to be true.

```
bys mother_id (father_id): gen byte one_husband = father_id[1] == father_id[_N]
bys father_id (mother_id): gen byte one_wife    = mother_id[1] == mother_id[_N]
gen byte touse = one_husband * one_wife
```

This solution ofcourse assumes that none of the mothers or fathers showing up in the Danish registry have children outside Denmark...

After that you can use the `touse` variable in whatever way you like. Typically I would prefer to use it as part of a `if` condition in subsequent analyses, but you can `keep` the observations for which `touse == 1`. You seem to want to impose this selection by  replacing some variable with missing values when `touse == 0`. That solution would be least attractive (i.e. I **strongly** recommend you do *not* do this), as you would change your data in a way that by no means guarantees that the selection you want is also applied in future analysis; it is just too indirect, too implicit to be good style.